# How can a docker container run privileged but that of a user on the host?

Tags: docker

Can a docker container be run privileged but that of a user?

I am trying to create a [TryHackMe!](https://tryhackme.com) room. My basic idea is to let users break out of a docker container, but can only gain access to a non-privileged user. However the only way I found out to break out of a docker container is running docker with `--privileged` flag but that gives root privilege to the container, which is undesirable. How can I let a docker container run with the privilege of a user so that users can break out of it, but still not gain root access?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the `--privileged` security issue. you can avoid this and achieve your requirement by assigning the container with specific user.

```
docker run -it -u <user> <container>
```

For further reference and complex requirements:

1. [userns-remap](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/)
2. [rootless](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/)

Comment: This does work, but breaking out of it fails. How can I fix it??

Comment: I am not sure what exactly do you mean when you say `breaking out it fails`. I am answering this what I understand
    if you want that container should run even if you come out of the container then try to run in daemon mode (with the option -d). in this case you can execute shell and other different command anytime and exit, container will continue to run in background.  
if this is not the case. Please elaborate your use case little bit.

Comment: To be honest, as I mentioned, I am creating a TryHackMe room. I want the docker container of mine to be vulnerable in some way, so that one can break out of it, but can only gain access to a non-privileged user. In my case, running the docker daemon as root , with the default installation, allows me to break out of the container successfully, however, it allows straightaway root access. I want my machine to be vulnerable in some way, but one can still break out of the docker container, and still gain access to a non-privileged user. I could not achieve this while running docker rootless

Comment: Have you tried the userns- remap. see this for reference:
https://coderwall.com/p/s_ydlq/using-user-namespaces-on-docker